# How to exit JFrame and keep data in the same positions?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener

```
package dragbutton_test;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DragButton_test extends JButton{

    private int draggedAtX, draggedAtY;

    public DragButton_test(String text){
        super(text);
        setDoubleBuffered(false);

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                draggedAtX = e.getX();
                draggedAtY = e.getY();
            }
        });

        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
                setLocation(e.getX() - draggedAtX + getLocation().x,
                            e.getY() - draggedAtY + getLocation().y);       
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        JButton button = new JButton("Save");
        button.setBounds(300, 480, 75, 25);
        frame.add(button);

        DragButton_test one = new DragButton_test("Michael");
        one.setBounds(0, 10, 85, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(one);

        DragButton_test two = new DragButton_test("Bob");
        two.setBounds(0, 40, 85, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(two);

        DragButton_test three = new DragButton_test("Joe");
        three.setBounds(0, 70, 85, 25);
        frame.getContentPane().add(three);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        frame.getContentPane(); 
        frame.setSize(700, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

**I need the save button in the JFrame to save where the user 
last moved the buttons. So every time the program is run, the 
buttons are in the same coordinates as before
I am not sure if this is possible however it would be amazing if you could fix it**
}

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do any approaches here seem like they will accomplish what you need: [Best way to store data between program runs in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285132/best-way-to-store-data-between-program-runs-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it. Using an [ObjectOutputSteam](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) is my personal favorite. This [tutorial](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.se/2011/04/java-file-save-and-file-load-objects.html) explains how to use them.

Or you can also simply write and read from a text file. Though I doubt it's as efficient.

Good luck coding.